# Create TWS monitoring task with specific job names

Tags: tivoli-work-scheduler

I work with TWS and monitor multiple jobs scheduled there.
I also have to check the list of about 20 jobs and I always have to filter the whole schedule by job name.
Is there any way to create custom task and filter the whole schedule by several specific job names?
There is an option to create task but it allows to monitor only one job name. 
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doJAQ.png)
Is it possible to monitor several job names simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

No multiple filters, you might use naming convention to allow to get them using a single filter.
In 9.5 you can also use folders instead of naming convention.